# TFS online error TF50316 when connection to server

Tags: azure-devops

Project was originally 2010, "converted" to 2013. Uploaded to TFS Online. I receive the following error when attempting to pull down via Source Control Explorer or when attempting to add new items to source control when opened locally:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Visual Studio

TF50316: The following name is not valid: App_Browsers. Verify that the 
name does not exceed the maximum character limit, only contains valid     
characters, and is not a reserved name.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I'm stumped. Suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered contacting [customer support for Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/cloud-services-assisted-support-vs) as this sounds like a connection or live site issue?

Comment: It's entered my mind. I was hoping to find a solution before sinking time into that. Failing a solution, I was thinking about blowing away the repo and readding it and seeing if the problem persisted. Thanks for the link. I'll look into that in the meantime.

Comment: That error can indicate a problem with the service, so I wouldn't suggest blowing the repo away, as it may well resolve itself if there is an issue at the VSO end.

Comment: My coworker can connect just fine as himself. We're wondering if maybe it's a user permission or set up problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular instance, it turns out that the workspace was corrupted. Deleting the workspace, creating a new local copy of the repo, connecting to the online repo via a new workspace corrected the problem. Creating a new workspace linking to the original copy of the local repo/code also did not exhibit the same problem.